# Regenerate CSRF Token If ajax request has an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax request to submit registration form. If a user submit form on first attempt with correct information, the request is working well. But If user made any mistake, correct the information and submit again, the data is inserted but in **console.log(data)**, I'm facing this error:

> "CSRF token mismatch."

> "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php".
> Line: 389.

head.blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My Blade view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send_form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /*Ajax Request Header setup*/
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $('#send_form').html('Sending..');
        /* Submit form data using ajax*/
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('register')}}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#ajax-register-form').serialize(),

            success: function(response) {


            $('#send_form').html('Submit');

            document.getElementById("ajax-register-form").reset();


              },
            error: function(data) {
              var errors = data.responseJSON;
              console.log(errors);
              $('.error-warning').show();

              }
        });
    });
  });
```

If user has an error on first attempt, the csrf token should regenerate so user can submit the form without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^8.54",

Comment: Seems you put the meta tag into wrong place. Make sure if the meta data for csrf-token on your browser.

Comment: meta tag is in the head

Comment: Did you solve your problem out? I can not reproduce the error on my local.

Comment: Yes I resolved the error. I mentioned the answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove headers from **$.ajaxSetup** and put it in send_form request like this.

```
$('#send_form').html('Sending..');
        /* Submit form data using ajax*/
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('register')}}",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: $('#ajax-register-form').serialize(),

            success: function(response) {


            $('#send_form').html('Submit');

            document.getElementById("ajax-register-form").reset();


              },
            error: function(data) {
              var errors = data.responseJSON;
              console.log(errors);
              $('.error-warning').show();

              }
        });
    });
```